# Akka cluster with version 2.5.13 is not coming up

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

We are trying to start an akka cluster with 2 seed nodes. From the debug logs it is visible that the gossip is happening and one of the nodes which has resolved as LEADER keeps trying to continuously mark both the seed nodes as UP. The log being printed repeatedly is:

Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://@ip1:port] to UP

Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://@ip2:port] to UP

The strange part is that this was all working fine till a few days ago and now this problem is visible across all the deployed instances.

We are using jboss netty 3.9.0 for transport and akka cluster 2.5.13. Could someone please point to what might be wrong here?

Comment: Can you add a link to the complete logs from each node? (For example, by pasting them into https://gist.github.com)

Comment: "The strange part is that this was all working fine ..." review what other changes on your deployment target my have had an impact (upgraded JVM, upgraded k8s, new mesh rules, etc...)

Comment: Yes I found the regression it was due to version change of another dependency. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, note that 2.5.13 is a rather old version. You may want to gradually upgrade to the newer [2.5.31](https://github.com/akka/akka/releases/tag/v2.5.31). If you do, make sure you follow the restrictions listed in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/additional/rolling-updates.html#rolling-updates (and related release notes) wrt Rolling Uprades.